# Fatal error: Class 'RDTheme' not found

Tags: plugins, themes, fatal-error

I am working with the Eikra theme and I have created a site that is perfectly working in the localhost. But I uploaded my website on the server and It is giving me this error.

Fatal error:

> Class 'RDTheme' not found in
>   /home/technobitz/domains/technobitz.in/public_html/new_website/wp-content/themes/eikra/page.php
>   on line 9

Comment: Did you upload whole theme folder and all plugins ?

Answer (score 0):

**class RDTheme** should be located in themes rdtheme.php file. 
Please check .../themes/eikra/inc/rdtheme.php file.

If you didn't find this file or folder in your live server then there might be some issue with your Wordpress migration from Localhost to Live server.

If you are not using a plugin to migrate your Wordpress site then you can try any popular migration plugin like *All-in-One WP Migration*, *Duplicator*, etc to transfer your website from localhost to live server.